Ubuntu systemd cpu usage 100% timezone
We found CPU usage of 99% by systemd on Ubuntu 22.04.1. It has something to do with the daylight-saving time switch.


Why didn't you install the latest security updates? The latest Ubuntu 22.04 version is 22.04.4. Maybe the bug has been fixed in the meantime.

Is this a known bug that already exists?

Not one that I know of, but updates are there for a reason.

update to 22.04.4 , the issue is alreay exists, and when When changing time zone by  timedatectl set-timezone  Europe/Dublin and before the daylight-saving time switch

Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS , systemd is already the newest version (249.11-0ubuntu3.12)

any suggestion ?

Not to pretend that I have some knowledge about this, but the first hit on Google using part of your title was this link and the second one that. Both claim it has something to do with the timezone, and setting it to UTC helps. Just my two cents.
